# Adding new menu to right click context menu in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have the following requirement,

When I right click any of the project file in visual studio 2012, solution explorer, I need to show the an extra context menu, In addition to the default menu. please let me know how to do that

Thanks,
Prakash.

Comment: I think these menus are all fixed. You cannot change.

Comment: You want to develop an Addin?

Comment: Irvin Dominin aka Edward, can you give me some examples ?